# Android Https OAuth 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: java, android, https, oauth-2.0

```
private void login() {
            androidID = Secure.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            String uP = androidID.concat(":ClientTrustedSecret");
            byte[] authByteAry = null;
            try {
                    authByteAry = uP.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(authByteAry, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
            client.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic ".concat(base64));
            // Following format is required to post to OAuth
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                    jsonObject.put("grant_type", "password");
                    jsonObject.put("username", "abc");
                    jsonObject.put("password", "abc");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            StringEntity data = null;
            try {
                    // Send the json to the server
                    data = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                    client.post(MainActivity.this, baseURL.concat("/tokens"), data, contentType, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                    try {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                            oauthAccessTokenString = jsonObject.get("access_token").toString();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable t, String err) {
                                    System.out.println("login failed");
                            }
                    });
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

The above is how I login. And when making another web serivce call I get the unauthorized. The unlock method requires the following headers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5oEG.png

```
private void unlock()
    {
            AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
            asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Locale", "en_US");
            asyncHttpClient.addHeader("X-Originator-Type", "app");
            asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//              asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
//              asyncHttpClient.addHeader("X-Device-Id", androidID);
//              asyncHttpClient.addHeader("X-via", deviceId);
//              asyncHttpClient.addHeader("ClientID", "abc@abc.com");
            asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ".concat(oauthAccessTokenString));
            asyncHttpClient.get("host/users?loginName=abc@abc.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                }
                @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t, String err) {
                            System.out.println("Unlock server call failed");
                            Log.d("printing error: ", err);
                    }
            });
    }
```

Above code throws 401 unauthorized exception. No references in documentation which I have, to call back url. I am providing the oauth access token just fine, but then why is it that I still get 401? Does the secret has anything to do with the second call? I am told is that I need to set up my headers that way. I am also told that "For https, the client needs to be able to handle the validation of the certificate. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I think my X-Device-Id could be wrong. I'm getting it in the login method. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a wrong web service address :( There was no need to handle the validation of the certificate. There was nothing about call back url. The secret had nothing to do. But the documentation that I have is very poorly written, at one place they mentioned only the headers and then in another place they say body is required is well. So just make sure you go through the documents properly.